# failed to set up gradle: 'Could not find the main class: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.'

Tags: java, gradle

I am new to gradle and I am getting started with the Installing Gradle guide.

When I follow the guide's 'Environment variables' step, I set GRADLE_HOME as /path/to/gradle and add /path/to/gradle/bin to the PATH in ~/.bashrc.

And I run gradle -v in the command line, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/launcher/GradleMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.  Program will exit.
```

it looks like the class path is missing so I set the CLASSPATH variable to '.:path/to/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-1.2.jar' and login again. It is still not working...

Any hints

Thx in Advance :)

Comment: maybe bad permissions on gradle jar files? see if you have read permissions for those.

Comment: Is there any symlink involved in your setup ?

Comment: I think this is going to be something really dumb - a kick-yourself moment of some kind.  Have you done a "which gradle" or otherwise made sure you're running the script you mean to?  Tried turning on -x on the gradle script?

Comment: is there 'gradle.bat' there? try to run without it (just rename it temporarily)

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to the environment file

PATH="... :$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
GRADLE_HOME="/opt/gradle/gradle-1.0-milestone-3"

Reload environment variables

source /etc/environment

Add symbolic links to the usr/bin folder

$ sudo ln -sf /opt/gradle/gradle-1.0-milestone-3/bin/* /usr/bin/.

Open a new terminal. Test installation using " gradle -v "

Answer (score 1):

I think using Homebrew(Package Management Software for Mac OSX) is much more easy to install and manage your all software packages if you are using Mac OSX.Today I installed gradle 2.0 by using brew command.

installing brew by using `brew install` and then update your `brew update` in order to get all current changes.

After you installed brew you can install all software packages by using brew

Command for installing Gradle:

```
brew install gradle
```

set environment of your gradle so you need to open .bash_profile in your terminal with this command: `vim .bash_profile`

After that you need to add this to your bash_profile

```
export GRADLE_HOME=$(/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/)
```

HomeBrew always install all software packages into /usr/local/Cellar but I recommend that check your gradle path in your terminal.

When you try  `gradle -v` you should see this:

---

### Gradle 2.0

Build time:   2014-07-01 07:45:34 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b6ead6fa452dfdadec484059191eb641d817226c

Groovy:       2.3.3
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_60 (Oracle Corporation 24.60-b09)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9.4 x86_64