# Trying to setup Gradle with Eclipse project error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, mapbox

Geeting this error in cmd :-

Error: couldnot find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.gradlemain

Comment: possible duplicate of [failed to set up gradle: 'Could not find the main class: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017354/failed-to-set-up-gradle-could-not-find-the-main-class-org-gradle-launcher-gra)

Comment: Thanks Krossovochkin   How to i fix this problem as i have followed all the steps of installation .

Comment: Are you limited to use of the Eclipse? I would suggest to migrate your project to Android Studio and use benefits of the Gradle from there, out of the box.